# Use jquery with ejs template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I'm trying to use jquery in an ejs template to make an input auto complete using an array sent by the server to the template.I get the following error :

```
ReferenceError: /var/www/html/DM/views/formulaire.ejs:8
    6| <title>Formulaire </title>
    7| </head>
 >> 8| <%
    9| $( "#depart" ).autocomplete({
    10|   source: autoComp
    11| });

$ is not defined
```

I made some researches and found out that you can't use client side javascript (jquery) with server side javascript (ejs), but i didn't find any solution.

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Formulaire </title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$( "#depart" ).autocomplete({
  source: autoComp
});
</script>

  <form action="/result" method="post">
    Départ:<input type="text" name="depart" id="depart"><br>
    Arrivée: <input type="text" name="arrivee"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Chercher un itinéraire">
  </form>
  <%
  if(erreur){
    %> <p>Erreur lors de la saisie des stations</p>
    <%
  }
  %>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT : No error anymore but auto completion doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put client side code in a `<script>` tag

Change

```
<%
$( "#depart" ).autocomplete({
  source: autoComp
});
%>
```

To

```
<script>
    $( "#depart" ).autocomplete({
      source: autoComp
    });
</script>
```

And put it inside the head or body

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this, i don't have the error anymore but auto completion doesn't work. In the script tags, do i have acces to the autoComp variable sent by the server ? When i try to print the variable in <% %> it works so it seems to be sent, but in <script> tags it doesn't seem to be working. I updated the code to let you see what i have now.

Comment: are you including an autocomplete plugin file? None shown above

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were creating the array in the action and passing it to the view. You then have to go one step further and pass it from the server-side view engine, to the actual browser engine.

```
<script>
  let autoComp = JSON.parse( `<%= JSON.stringify( autoComp ) %>` );
```

What this does:

- tells the EJS engine to render the array as a JSON string
- (note the backticks, you need some kind of quotation mark because it's a string)
- The browser-side JS engine then runs that string through JSON.parse

Obviously this ability only works one-way; to get a variable from the browser to the EJS you need to commit an action (POST/GET).

You may also need some substitutions to make the string play nice, such as:

```
function fixForJSON(val) {
  return val.replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
}
function fixForDisplay(val) {
  return val.replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
}
```

If you really want to do this:

```
<%
  $(selector).doStuff();
```

You need to pass the JQuery object itself, into the template variables.

E.g. in your node code:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const jquery = require('jquery');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
const $ = jquery(dom.window);
global.jq = $;
```

Then in your specific route action (still node code)

```
var locals = { // the var you are sending to the EJS template
  jq: global.jq,
```

And finally in your EJS you can:

```
const $ = jq;
var testDiv = $('<div>').html('hello jquery in the template').appendTo('body');
console.log($('body').html());
```